# Sum of amicable numbers -- Euler task 21

Tags: python

```
def f(a):
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,a):
        if(a%i==0):
            sum=sum+i

    return sum

sum2=0
for i in range(1,10000):
    q=f(i)
    if f(q)==i:
        sum2=sum2+i

print(f(sum2))
```

I wrote this for [project euler problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21) and its gave to me 64436.
Unfornutely I couldnt find my mistake by myself. Where is my mistake?

> Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less
>   than n which divide evenly into n). If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a
>   ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called
>   amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20,
>   22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284
>   are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

Comment: It's difficult to help you without proper information about what you're trying to do. So what are you trying to do? We need context.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  What is the correct output, and what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ This is not a code dump website. Please make an effort to debug your code before dumping it here.

Comment: In particular, "I couldnt find my mistake" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 4):

Just print `sum2` and not `f(sum2)`. `sum2` should already represent the sum of all amicable numbers, which is what the problem asks for.